# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre REGEXP y RLIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Intentaba hacer una consulta para consultar la lista de nombres de CITY de STATION que no comienzan con vocales y no terminan con vocales. Su resultado no puede contener duplicados. Me di cuenta de que

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

En efecto me da :

> ```
> Arlington 
> Turner 
> Slidell 
> Negreet 
> Glencoe
> ```

Pero la manera con `REGEXP`, que ya no conozco excepto que parece referirse a expresiones regulares, fonciona :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^AEIUO].*[^AEIOU]$'
```

¿Pueden explicarme por qué el primero no funciona?

#### Actualización

Parece que el problema esta con `NOT RLIKE ...` dado que :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

funciona pero no entiendo muy bien la subitlidad con `^[^...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RLIKE` es un sinónimo de `REGEXP` (ver [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)). No hay ninguna diferencia entre usar uno o el otro.

#### Diferencias entre negar una clase o negar el resultado

- `[aeiouAEIOU]` es una **clase de caracteres**: coincide con uno de esos (una vocal).
- `[^aeiouAEIOU]` es una **clase de caracteres negada**: coincide con un caracter, cualquiera que no sea uno de esos.

No es lo mismo comprobar que no empiece y termine con vocal

```
WHERE Campo NOT REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

a que tenga que empezar y terminar con una letra que no sea una vocal.

```
WHERE Campo REGEXP '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Por ejemplo, los siguientes valores coincidirían con el primero pero no con el segundo:

```
     /* string vacío */
A
AZ
AbcdeZ
BU
BcdefU
```